# Spyder shows warning in import section

Tags: python-3.x

Why spyder shows warning when i import library as "from array import *" but the code runs without warning? It feels irritating to me. please help me out.

Comment: What does the warning say?

Comment: see [Why is “import *” bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2386714/10197418). It will just clutter you namespace with stuff you don't know about ;-)